# How to set "\pset null (null)" by default?

Tags: psql

To make psql display NULL properly, I can do one of the followings:

(1) Execute `\pset null (null)` every time

(2) Start psql with `-P 'null=(null)'`

Any better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways.

(1) Use `~/.psqlrc` config file. Simply put `\pset null (null)` inside the file.

(2) Create an alias in `.bashrc` in Linux or `.bash_profile` in MacOS, for example: `alias psql="psql -P 'null=(null)'"`